# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript

Gives an error. I have placed the code just before `</body>`. Still getting the error.

```
<form action="" method="get" id="searchform" >
<input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt">
<input type="button" id="hit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction();return false" class="btn">   
</form>
```

JS,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nexturl = "";
    var lastid = "";
    var param;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function myFunction() {
            param = $('#search').val();
            alert("I am an alert box!");
            if (param != "") {
                $("#status").show();
                var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=100&q=' + param;
                getResults(u);
            }
        }
        $("#more").click(function () {
            $("#status").show();
            $("#more").hide();
            pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
            var u = nexturl;
            getResults(u);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `$(document).ready()` construct. It's not needed when you have your code at the bottom.

Comment: Bind the event handler with jQuery instead of using `onclick`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot place `myFunction` after the `onclick`. When the `onclick` is seen there is no definition for `myFunction`.

Place the JavaScript in `<head>` tag. Also, move the function outside of `ready()`.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nexturl ="";
var lastid ="";
var param;

function myFunction() {
    param = $('#search').val();
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    if (param != "") {
        $("#status").show();
        var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=100&q='+param;
        getResults(u);
        }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#more").click(function () { 

    $("#status").show();
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if `myFunction` is before or after the `onclick` attribute. It only matters that it is hidden in the variable scope of the `.ready()` handler..

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Moved the code outside but still it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Moved the function outside the ready block and moved the complete code in the head and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

keep myFunction  in script tag directly

```
 i.e
   <script>

function myFunction() {
  .....  
}
 </script>
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution with this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

So your function isn't created until after your onclick is established. Thus it can't find the function. You'll want to move it outside the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: @FahadUddin What happens the second time? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: The function runs again but does not perform the task it perfomrms at first

Comment: @FahadUddin It's working for me; however, the returned results are being appended to the current status list. Maybe they should replace it?

Comment: Thanks. I just observed that.

Comment: Just add `$('#data').empty()` to the top of the `success` function, if you don't want the previous results to persist. And if you found my answer helpful, feel free to mark it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the function outside the `$document.ready` here then you will have two options: 1st move it to `<head>` or 2nd move it right before the closing `$document.ready` bracket. Use this type of declaration for your function `myFunction(){alert("inside my function");};`