# Using Function onChange

Tags: javascript

I have a text input:

```
<input class="stops" id="stops" onchange="stopsChanged();">
```

And my current JavaScript looks like:

```
<script>
  function stopsChanged(){
    alert();
  }
</script>
```

But when I run my code, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: stopsChanged is not defined

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It is working perfectly fine at my end. It might be you have written some other script above this function which is not valid

Comment: The code alone should work, assuming it is all in the same page?

Comment: no it's not in the same page. My javascript code is on anther page.

Comment: then it won't work... the script and element must be there in the same page

Comment: Make sure your `js file` and html file in the same location. And you should inlcude the `js` file in your `html` file

Comment: I already did. I have many functions and all of them is working. Only this one it's not. Could it be the input with the function onchange ?

Comment: Where you include your file ? means it is in top of the html code or bottom. My suggestion is include at the end.

Comment: I am including my files in a php file. then in a file named confirmation.php  I have my html. And my functions are in a .js file.
All my functions are working.

Comment: The code in the question [works](http://jsbin.com/kuderobojo/1/edit?html,output), whatever the problem is, it isn't caused by anything you've shown us.

Comment: You're totally right.I'm trying more to know where's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include your `JS` file on the page your `<input>` is on like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

What probably happens is that you include your `JS` file **after** the `<input>` is loaded in the `DOM`. This way HTML tries to access your `function` before it's even there. Try to put your `<script>` in the `<head>` of your `HTML` and make sure it isn't in a `.ready()` function or something similar to it.

Source of above: [Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171294/uncaught-referenceerror-myfunction-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Nejthe I did more research and edited my answer according to what I've found.

Comment: There is no need to use an external file. There is no need to use a type attribute. Including the JS after the input doesn't matter - the HTML won't try to access the function until the event handler is fired.

Comment: Check the source I've added before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have HTML  tags inside of your external javascript file.  You do not need to wrap your external javascript code with html  tags in the contents of the .js file.

In your HTML file though, make sure you define your script type in the opening tag if you're using an external file reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yoursource.com/file.js"></script>
```

In some browsers, it will not know how to parse the external resource without the type being defined in the opening tag.

Comment: Script type is optional and by default equal to text/javascript

Comment: @aduch, If the script is defined within the brackets, then you are right.  However, not if the script resource is external via a 'src' attribute in the script tag.

Comment: You are right for HTML<= 4 or (x)HTML, but not for HTML5. Anyways, there  is rarely too much information about these kind of answers

Comment: @Nejthe, The only thing I can think of is improper syntax in one of the other functions above your stopsChanged() function definition.  This would be an unclosed/open bracket somewhere that is breaking the browser when it parses the external file.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way.

HTML:

```
<input id="stops">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('stops').onchange = function(){
    console.log('test');   
}
```

It's also better in terms of separation of function and presentation.